# Abandoned commit on Gerrit

Tags: git, gerrit

I have script to cherry-pick commits to `refs/for/master`

And someone can abandon commits.

After `git pull` I don't see that commit was abondoned.

Is it possible to get information about abandoned commit from local repo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[From that gist](https://gist.github.com/Rud5G/5604323), you could query all commits abandonned, and see if your commit is part of that list:

```
# get all abandoned commit number ids for the project YOUR_PROJECT_NAME
gerrit query 'status:abandoned project:YOUR_PROJECT_NAME' | egrep '^\ +number' | cut -d' ' -f4- > $tmpfileids
```

But that is from the remote Gerrit referential, *not* from your local repository.